# Set automatically the width of a table, based on the column width in which the table appears (in a 2-column document)

Tags: tabularx, two-column, width, paracol, column-width

I have a document that is split into two columns of different width. In one of the two columns, I would like to add a table that is large exactly as the width of that column. Is there an automatic way to set the table width exactly as the column width where it appears?

In the following example I use `paracol` to split the document into two columns. In particular, I set the width of the left column as `\columnratio{0.6}`. Now, instead of writing `\begin{tabularx}{0.4\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}` for the width of the table in the right column, is there an automatic way (like a way to assign the variable "width") to the table? Something like `\begin{tabularx}{{1-\columnratio{0.6}}\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.6}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \lipsum[1]
    \switchcolumn
    \lipsum[1]
    \\
    \begin{tabularx}{0.395\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
     \hline item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\
     \hline item 21 & item 22 & item 23 \\
     \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|X|X|X|}`?

Comment: Issue solved, thanks a lot! If you put it in an Answer, I accept it :-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please see the answer I've posted in the meantime (which I wrote *before* seeing @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's comment).

Comment: @Mico Nice solution :P

Comment: Oh gosh, you guys are very fast in replying! :-) Thanks a lot to both of you!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I have just seen that answer, thanks to your comment. I did not know about (i) \columnwidth and (ii) the possibility to use \columnwidth within a two-column framework. Therefore, I think I could not be able to find that answer in regard to my problem. If you think this is a duplicate question, I will delete it, or please go ahead. Thanks again! :-)

Comment: @Ommo No need to delete your question. Adding a duplicate just means that future users with the same problem will find additional reading material about the topic.

Comment: Ah ok, I did not know, thanks! ...However, I have just seen that someone suggested to close this question.. Maybe a moderator, I do not know..  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you change `0.395\textwidth` to `\columnwidth`. (`\linewidth` works too.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol,lipsum,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.6}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \lipsum[1]
    \switchcolumn
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|X|X|X|}
       \hline 
       item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\
       \hline 
       item 21 & item 22 & item 23 \\
       \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```